# How to get all the group names irrespective of users in django?

Tags: python, django-admin

```py
groups = request.user.groups.all()
```

Using the above command, I am getting only the groups of a particular user. But I would like to get all the group names which are available in Django admin. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the groups by importing them.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

groups = Group.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
```

borrowed from:
[Django: How to get the list of the usergroups and use that list (dictionary) as a choice options for a model field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860092/django-how-to-get-the-list-of-the-usergroups-and-use-that-list-dictionary-as)